# Add separation lines to fieldset

Tags: html, line, fieldset

Is there a way to add separation lines in a fieldset? Something like

---

but I want the lines to go full across the fieldset and also be able to change the color.

Here's an axample to help visualise what I want to do... the red line being the added line.

[image: fieldset with added line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with CSS like this:

```
fieldset {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #FF0000;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

You just add a CSS rule to the fieldset element, then add a border with the thick and color, then a margin to move next fieldset or element a little bit down. You might need to add a padding to make the red line a little bit further from last element.